# IOS jailbroken ssh/mobileterminal alerts from command line

Tags: ssh, terminal, jailbreak, openssh, cydia

i was wondering if there is a command for the IOS ssh or mobileterminal to make an alert popup or if there is a terminal addon in cydia to add this functionality.

thanks for any help! :)

Comment: are you trying to write such a program yourself, or use an existing, off-the-shelf tool?  normally, Stack Overflow is for programming questions ... that said, I haven't voted to close your question ... just a comment.

Comment: yea i know it is just for programming questions usually but i saw another person post a question like this on stack over flow and they got good results so i thought i would give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for sbutils from cydia. It comes with a tool called sbalert which will allow you to do that. If you need help type `sbalert --h or sbalert --help`

Comment: Here's the [Github](https://github.com/innoying/iOS-sbutils), if anyone is wondering